# python logging set level in basicConfig

Tags: python

python logging set level in basicConfig:

```
import logging

def show(level):
    logging.basicConfig(level=level)
    logging.info('info')
    logging.debug('debug')
    logging.warn('warn')
    logging.error('error')
    logging.fatal('fatal')
    logging.warning('warning')
    logging.critical('critical')
    logging.exception('exception')

show(logging.WARNING)
show(logging.DEBUG)
```

The two results are the same, how to get what I expects?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [logging.basicConfig documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging#logging.basicConfig), the second call to logging.basicConfig does not take effect.

> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers
>   configured for it.

```
def show(level):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logging.info('info')
    ....
```