# tkinter ImageTk creates unwanted logs in the log file

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

When I use the PIL.ImageTk library to load a png to my GUI and use logging to log some events, it creates some unwanted logs in DEBUG mode.

I have tried changing the `level` of `logging` to `INFO` or `WARNING` (or higher). But that does not help:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='mylog.log', filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', level=logging.INFO)
```

For example, the following code will create a log file with some unwanted lines:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import logging

try:
    import tkinter as tk # Python 3.x
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk # Python 2.x

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        for i in range(2):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('test.png'))
        logo = tk.Label(self, image = self.img)
        logo.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nw", pady=5, padx=10)

        testLabel = tk.Label(self, width=8, text="This is a test")
        testLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew', padx=5, pady=5)
        logging.info("This is a test log...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(filename='mylog.log', filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', level=logging.DEBUG)

    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Here is a sample image `test.png`

[image]

This will create a log file with some unwanted lines like this:

```
07/23/2019 01:34:23 PM DEBUG: STREAM b'IHDR' 16 13
07/23/2019 01:34:23 PM DEBUG: STREAM b'IDAT' 41 6744
07/23/2019 01:34:23 PM INFO: This is a test log...
```

It should have been only:

```
07/23/2019 01:34:23 PM INFO: This is a test log...
```

If you remove the image from the GUI, the problem goes away. Is there any workaround for this?

EDIT: I apologize for not going through the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) carefully. This was happening because the root module was created with DEBUG level when I first ran the script in Spyder with `level=DEBUG` and it was never changed by `basicConfig` subsequently when I changed the level to INFO. If I reload all the modules and libs (only by restarting the kernel in Spyder), the problem goes away, which means `level=INFO` would work perfectly as I want.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are you saying that even when you set the log level to INFO, the log contains DEBUG messages?

Comment: if I'm not wrong it doesn't change `level` when you use `basicConfig`. Maybe some bug.

Comment: problem can be because module already set level and now `basicConfig` can't change it: [python logging set level in basicConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848281/python-logging-set-level-in-basicconfig). Maybe if you create new logger then you get only your messages in logger.

Comment: I apologize for not going through the docs carefully. @BryanOakley: Yes, even if I set the log level to INFO, I was getting DEBUG messages. The reason was the root module was created with DEBUG level when I first ran the script and it was never changed by `basicConfig` subsequently when I changed the level to INFO. If I reload all the modules and libs (only by restarting the kernel in Spyder), the problem goes away. @furas: Thanks, you saved my day!

Answer (score 4):

Add:

```
pil_logger = logging.getLogger('PIL')
pil_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

(source: https://github.com/camptocamp/pytest-odoo/issues/15#issuecomment-559203242)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is because module already created root logger and now `basicConfig` uses this logger but it can't change level for existing logger.

Doc: [basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)

> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it.

You have to create own logger (you can use `__name__` to make it unique) and then you can set root level and levels for file and console handlers. In own logger you will no see warnings from other loggers.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # root level

    # console
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # level only for console (if not collide with root level)
    logger.addHandler(ch)

    # file
    fh = logging.FileHandler('mylog.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # level only for file (if not collide with root level)
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Doc: [logging-advanced-tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial),

Answer (score 0):

Instead Of Using:

```
...
level=logging.DEBUG
...
```

Use:

```
...
level=logging.INFO
...
```

And Your File Will Be:

> DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS PM INFO: This is a test log...